# Regex: capture specific string with conditions

Tags: python, regex, string, substring

Im trying to just capture the following string: `u00` because i need to replace it to `\u00`.

Sometimes this characters appear with a `\` before, in that case, i don't want to capture it.
At other times, the simbol is `"`, i want to capture it, but just the `u00`, not `"u00`

Im trying this:

```
file_modified = re.sub(r'[^\\|^\s](u00)', r'\\u00', original_file)
```

Im capturing the `"` and i don't know how to skip it, i just want to capture `u00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just match it optionally:

```py
file_modified = re.sub(r'\\?u00', r'\\u00', original_file)
```

Here,

- `\\?u00`  - matches an optional `\` and `u00`
- `\\u00` - is a replacement pattern that replaces with `\u00`

Thus, even if there was a `\` before `u00`, it won't disappear and won't get doubled, but if it was missing, it will be added.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/9zJAdn):

```py
import re
original_file = r"u00 because i need to replace it to \u00"
print(re.sub(r'\\?u00', r'\\u00', original_file))
# => \u00 because i need to replace it to \u00
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative lookbehind assertion `r'(?<!\\)(u00)'`.  The will match `u00` provided it is not preceded by `\`.